# Fresh install of 14.04, can't boot

Tags: boot, 14.04, unetbootin

I had Fedora 20 installed on my laptop, but last night I used UNetbootin to make a bootable Ubuntu USB stick. Installed Ubuntu 14.04, everything went fine, but when I restarted the laptop I got a black screen with a purple border. When I restarted the computer again, I got this screen:

[image]

I decided to try to install Xubuntu, and when I tried to boot from the USB it took me to GRUB, and when I attempted to boot up Ubuntu I got the above screen again.

Note: I had Ubuntu running seamlessly on my laptop before installing Fedora, so I know it's compatible with my hardware!